# Как узнать размер файла без скачивания?

Tags: php

В php как то можно узнать размер файла по ссылке без скачивания самого файла?
Что то на подобии этого:

```
filesize('http://wallpapers-images.ru/1920x1080/mountains/wallpapers/mountains-wallpapers-1920x1080-0007.jpg');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем, если сервер эту инфу выдаёт - то она есть в HTTP-заголовках, а именно в  заголовке `Content-Length`.

Чтобы получить набор HTTP-заголовков, не нужно делать запрос GET (он приведет к скачиванию файла, а Вы хотите этого избежать, не так ли?). Достаточно сделать запрос HEAD.

Я из руководства по PHP накопипастил кусок, который выводит все заголовки. Там надо смотреть на заголовок, который называется `Content-Length`, в данном случае он равен 763016

```
        <?

    $url = "http://wallpapers-images.ru/1920x1080/mountains/wallpapers/mountains-wallpapers-1920x1080-0007.jpg";

    // По умолчанию функция get_headers использует GET-запрос для получения заголовков. Если
    // вы хотите вместо него отправить HEAD-запрос, то это можно сделать, используя контекста потока:
    stream_context_set_default(
        array(
            'http' => array(
                'method' => 'HEAD'
            )
        )
    );

    $resp = get_headers( $url, 1);
    ?>

    <?=var_dump($resp);?>
```

Comment: По-моему писать ручками HTTP/1.0 в сырой сокет в то время как всюду сплошной HTTPS и HTTP/3 это немного перебор)

Comment: @andreymal - с критикой согласен, сейчас переделаю!

Comment: я не отказываюсь, на на самом деле - вы зря плюсуете мой ответ... По сути, ответ на Ваш вопрос дал KoVadim - а мой ответ отличается только тем, что я погуглил за Вас :-)

Answer (score 4):

Можно. Нужно просто сделать head запрос, а не get. И если сервер будет добрым, то он в заголовках выставит размер содержимого в Content-Length - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.get-headers.php (там же есть и пример)